# Difference between drawing with QPainter and (QGraphicsView + QGraphicsScene)

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to the QT libraries, and I wanted to know what the difference is between QPainter and QGraphicsScene.

From what I understand by seeing voidrealms videos with [QPainter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5JE5ek_oN_0&index=74&list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63) 
and with [QGraphicsView + QGraphicsScene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b35JF4LqtBs&index=81&list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63) with both you can draw complex 
2d objects.

The main difference being in the latter have an arbitrarily large scene which we view through a "window" (I believe Qt guys call it viewport?) and that this scene can be scrolled with side-bars. Also we 
can interact with drawings made in a GraphicsView widget, say with a mouse, but in a QPainter we cannot.

Is this correct?

In what use cases do we use QPainter and when do we use QGraphicsScene+QGraphicsView? I am primarily interested in making animations of some algorithms in computational geometry, so it seems I will be working with the latter.

I am using Qt5.6.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`QGraphicsItem` itself uses `QPainter` for drawing, so your question is ill-formed.

Qt offers 3 different APIs for graphics - `QWidget` based, `QGraphicsScene` stack based and `QtQuick` based.

`QWidget` is for "typical" GUI rectangular elements, buttons, checkboxes, drop down menus and whatnot. Widgets are `QObject` derived so you get signals/slots and such. It is optimal for typical user interface items, not so much for custom graphics, although they are still completely possible to implement.

`QGraphicsScene` as the name implies, is a graphics scene, you can scroll, scale, rotate the scene, the scene and the view are separate objects, drawing itself is identical to widgets, but the paradigm is not the typical for widgets "draw a GUI", also `QGraphicsItem` itself is not `QObject` derived, so you don't have the signals/slots and such, although you can use `QGraphicsObject` if you need them. The regular graphics item is more lightweight, supports LOD drawing and some extra functionality not part of the widgets API. There are a few stock graphics items such as lines, rectangles and whatnot, similar to how there are stock widgets, for everything custom, you have to implement your own painting using `QPainter`, just like with widgets. Being more lightweight and supporting LODs, you can have a significantly higher object count than widgets.

`QtQuick` is the most recent graphics API, available since Qt5, it uses QML rather than C++, and is very easy and fast to develop and prototype in it. Animations and custom graphics elements are fastest and easiest to implement with QML. It can be extended with custom C++ types, including graphics items, either using `QPainter` or the QML scenegraph API, the latter of which is a little more complex to extend. You also have a `Canvas` element, which has an API similar to `QPainter` which you can use directly. This API is heavier than the graphics scene, even heavier than the widgets because of the extra functionality, but thanks to the scenegraph, graphics performance is usually much better than widgets or the graphics scene, even if you combine them with OpenGL.

Comment: LOD stands for level of detail - when objects get smaller you use faster draw routines drawing less detailed objects

Comment: @ddriver Can you point to some info about LOD in `QGraphicsItem`? I can see `QStyleOptionGraphicsItem::levelOfDetailFromTransform(wxform)` which works in conjunction with `QGraphicsScene::minimumRenderSize()` but I can't see any way for the graphics item to get notified when LOD crosses certain thresholds (so it can change how it will get painted). Or would you make the call to `levelOfDetailFromTransform` in the item's `paint()` method, and have say `if (lod < 0.5) ... else ...`?

Comment: @Schollii - take a look at the chips example, it implements LOD: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-chip-example.html

Comment: @ddriver thanks, indeed the `Chip::paint` method uses return value of call to `levelOfDetailFromTransform()` on the `QStyleOptionGraphicsItem` instance received as argument to `paint()`, brilliant! For others interested in this, it's all in [Chip.cpp specifically](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-chip-chip-cpp.html).

Answer (score 5):

`QPainter` is what lets you manipulate pixels on a widget. `QGraphicsView` uses it internally to render the contents of the scene. If you use any custom items in a scene, you'll have to write your own rendering code that uses `QPainter` to render them. The graphics scene framework lets you manage your geometry in a tree of items, and provides for easy manipulation of the items. No matter what you do, it's still always `QPainter` that does the drawing. If your geometry is simple or doesn't need to be interactive and/or hierarchical, use `QPainter` directly. Otherwise, use the graphics scene, or QML's scene geometry that's then rendered via OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

QGraphicView offers you to make something like a Theater. Items are actors which could be made of predefined drawings and Items that Qt offers, or your custome Items for which you need QPainter to draw them. The secnce which store and manage all items and the view is the container/background that the scene uses to paly on that. This is the power you get from this Framework. In fact the real functionalities come from all those Absract classes that you can use to make eveyrthing custome for your usecases. Qpainter can only give you the possibilty to draw an item and show it on some QpaintingDevice with using some functionalies that the engin gives you.